# Objective C - Know when a method finish

Tags: xml, parsing, methods, download

I explain better my question : when my app start, some xml have been downloaded from the internet and this files have been parsed. I have 8 xml file. My question is : how can i know when really the parser finish to parse? And when all data is ready to download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using NSXMLParser, then your delegate is notified when the end of the document is reached using [– parserDidEndDocument:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSXMLParserDelegate/parserDidEndDocument%3a)

Comment: And if i would to know when a file has been downloaded? How can i do? If i have a method that download a file, how can i know if this method has finished or not?

Comment: If you download it synchronously, then the answer is obvious. And if you're downloading it async, then, again, the delegate is notified with http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/connectionDidFinishLoading: